# SQL count distinct empty values Oracle / Redshift

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct, amazon-redshift

I'm having different results between Oracle and Redshift when I do a count(distinct my_field).

Assuming my_field has the following values : "", a, b c.

Oracle's count distinct will give me 3.
Redshift's count distinct will give me 4 (unless I specifically add a clause testing length > 0).

Has anyone seen this before ?
Is there a way to set up the database so it ignores empty values in a distinct count ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: ANSI SQL counts values, but not NULL's.

Comment: The issue is that in Oracle, unlike other databases, an empty string is treated as a NULL value. If you are not interested in counting empty values, perhaps you should consider storing NULL in the field instead of an empty string.

Comment: @sstan - that is an answer (and the correct answer) so perhaps it would be best to post it that way. Nitpick: "storing" is not the right term, since Oracle "stores" NULL regardless of how you input it (even if you say insert into... value (''), Oracle will store NULL).

Comment: @mathguy: I was referring to the redshift database (I wasn't clear) which is where OP is experiencing the problem. You're right that in Oracle, it wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Oh, I got it. Perhaps you could edit your comment to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

```
## CREATE TABLE

dev=# create table my_table (my_key integer null, my_field varchar null) diststyle even;
CREATE TABLE

## LOAD DATA
dev=# insert into my_table values (0, 'A');
INSERT 0 1
dev=# insert into my_table values (1, 'B');
INSERT 0 1
dev=# insert into my_table values (2, 'C');
INSERT 0 1
dev=# insert into my_table values (3, NULL);
INSERT 0 1
dev=# insert into my_table values ( NULL, 'E');
INSERT 0 1
dev=# insert into my_table values (6, NULL);
INSERT 0 1
dev=# insert into my_table values (7, NULL);
INSERT 0 1
dev=# insert into my_table values (8, 'A');
INSERT 0 1

##CHECK CONTENTS OF TABLE
dev=# SELECT * FROM my_table;
 my_key | my_field 
--------+----------
      0 | A
      2 | C
      3 | 
        | E
      1 | B
      6 | 
      7 | 
      8 | A
(8 rows)

## DISTINCT RESULTS
dev=# SELECT DISTINCT my_field FROM my_table;
 my_field 
----------
 C

 E
 B
 A
(5 rows)

dev=# SELECT COALESCE(my_field, 'NULL')  FROM my_table GROUP BY 1 ;                                                                                                
coalesce 
----------
 A
 NULL
 C
 E
 B
(5 rows)

dev=# SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(my_field, 'NULL')  FROM my_table WHERE my_field ;
ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type character varying
dev=# SELECT DISTINCT my_field  FROM my_table WHERE my_field IS NOT NULL;
 my_field 
----------
 B
 C
 E
 A
(4 rows)

dev=#
```